# OnItemSelectedListener in a Fragment that uses a custom Adapter not responding

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a list in a fragment with custom cells adapter,

The problem is that the onItemSelected is not responding,

how to fix this please?

```
public class PhoneMenuList extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Fragment newContent = null;
ListView productList;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    return mView; 
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //SET THE LIST ADAPTER!
    Hamburger hambu_data[] = new Hamburger[] {
                new Hamburger(R.drawable.icon_hambu_folder, "My Documents"),
                new Hamburger(R.drawable.icon_hambu_favs, "Top 10 viewed"),
                new Hamburger(R.drawable.icon_hambu_validate, "Validate Document"),
                new Hamburger(R.drawable.icon_hambu_how, "How to use"),
                new Hamburger(R.drawable.icon_hambu_about, "About")
            };              

      productList= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      HamburgerAdapter adapter = new HamburgerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.hamburger_item_row, hambu_data);          

        productList= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.hamburger_item_row, null);
        productList.addHeaderView(header);
        productList.setAdapter(adapter);

        //listener          
        productList.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

 //@Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("mensa", "chapuzea");
 }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("mensa", "abacus");
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("mensa", "semper");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you initializing listview twice ?

`productList= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

and use `setOnItemClick()` instead of `setOnItemSelected()`

remove `productList.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

use  `productList.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a choice mode to your ListView. [setChoiceMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29)

Comment: hi thanks, I set         // productList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 but still no response

Answer (score 0):

You can override onListItemClick method of SherlockListFragment.

Try this Code.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   System.out.println("onListItemClick");
}
```

or instead of using `OnItemSelectedListener` use `OnItemClickedListener`.